# IdentityServer4 All Client Scopes in Token

Tags: identityserver4, identitymodel

I have a multitenant app secure with an IdentityServer4 implementation.  I recently updated it to the latest ID4 and the behavior seems to have changed.  Previously, I could make a request with the TokenClient inside of the IdentityModel package:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

parameters.Add("username", loginModel.UserName);
parameters.Add("password", loginModel.Password);
var tokenClient = new TokenClient(new Uri(new Uri(accountsConfig.EndpointUrl), "/connect/token").ToString(), accountsConfig.ClientId, accountsConfig.Secret,  null, AuthenticationStyle.PostValues); 

var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestCustomGrantAsync("AgentLogin", extra: parameters);
```

It would return all of the scopes defined for the client in the token.  That is no longer the case.  How do I configure ID4 to do that without explicitly requesting them inside of the TokenClient?

```
public class AgentLoginCustomGrantValidator : IExtensionGrantValidator
    {
        private readonly ILogger<AgentLoginCustomGrantValidator> _logger;
        private readonly IAdminUserService _adminUserService;

        public AgentLoginCustomGrantValidator(ILogger<AgentLoginCustomGrantValidator> logger, IAdminUserService adminUserService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _adminUserService = adminUserService;
        }

        public async Task ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var username = context.Request.Raw.Get("username");
                var password = context.Request.Raw.Get("password");

                var userId = _adminUserService.AuthenticateUser(username, password);


                if (userId != null)
                {
                    var agencyUser = _adminUserService.GetUser(userId.Value);
                    context.Result = new GrantValidationResult($"{userId}", GrantType, agencyUser.Roles.Select(x => new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, x.Name)).Concat(new List<Claim>() { new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, agencyUser.UserName) { } }));

                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning($"Bum creds: {username} ");
                    context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidClient, "Invalid credentials");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidClient, ex.Message);

            }
        }

        public string GrantType => "AgentLogin";
    }
```

Comment: Share the code of your custom grant please.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Done

Comment: What exactly is no longer the case? You mean that TokenClient is now obsolete?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Identity Server 4 by default only returns the requested identity or api resources for each client. However, this behaviour can be easily overridden to return all the scopes regardless whether they were requested in the token request or not. You can create a `CustomClaimsService` which inherits from the `DefaultClaimsService`.

```
public class CustomClaimsService : DefaultClaimsService
{
    public CustomClaimsService(IProfileService profile, ILogger<DefaultClaimsService> logger) : base(profile, logger)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetAccessTokenClaimsAsync(ClaimsPrincipal subject,
        Resources resources, ValidatedRequest request)
    {
        var baseResult = await base.GetAccessTokenClaimsAsync(subject, resources, request);
        var outputClaims = baseResult.ToList();

        //If there are any allowed scope claims that are not yet in the output claims - add them
        foreach (var allowedClientScope in request.Client.AllowedScopes)
        {
            if (!outputClaims.Any(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Scope && x.Value == allowedClientScope))
            {
                outputClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, allowedClientScope));
            }
        }

        return outputClaims;
    }
}
```

Then just register it with the `IdentityServerBuilder` service container.

```
        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            //Your identity server options
        });

        //Register the custom claims service with the service container
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IClaimsService, CustomClaimsService>();
```

Each access token will now contain all the scopes that the given client is allowed.